# Парсинг строки

Tags: c#, массивы, синтаксический-анализ, строки

Добрый день.

Нужно распарсить строку, проделать некоторые действия с ней и вернуть потом то, что получилось, тоже строкой.

У меня есть строка :

`rates = "50.8,10,1;0.0001,60,0;50,0,0;"`

Есть параметр

`OpenDate = '01.04.2014'`

и

`EndDate = '01.04.2016'`

Нужно разделить стоку на 3 части, разделять по ";", тоесть 
rates.Split(new char[]{';'}), получится :

`50.8,0,1`

`0.0001,60,0`

`50,0,0`

Потом нужно взять вторые числа с масива и прибавить к OpenDate в днях.

Тоесть:

`"01.04.2014" + 0 дней`

`"01.04.2014" + 60 дней`

`"01.04.2014" + 0 дней`

Это будет

`OpenDate.AddDays(item)`

Последнее число в строке означает какая строка будет выше. тоесть, если последняя цыфра = 1 - она должна быть сверху

В конце нужно собрать строку, которая имела б вид :

`"50.8   01.04.2014 
 0.0001 31.05.2014
 50     01.04.2014 "`

Как то так.

Вопрос : как лучше реализовать такое вот задание?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А давайте поупражняемся в LINQ?

```
string.Join(
    "\n",
    from parts in rates.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Select(p => p.Split(',')
                                     .Select(double.Parse).ToList())
    let date = OpenDate.AddDays(parts[1])
    let output = string.Format("{0}\t{1:d}", parts[0], date)
    orderby parts[2] descending
    select output);
```

Comment: .Select(double.Parse).ToList())
не хочет парсится (( 

Но спасибо за наводку.

Comment: @VladD: 4.0

Comment: @Telsystems: Хм. Странно. Вот вам полная рабочая программа: http://pastebin.com/DdMf541N

Попробуйте откомпилировать и скажите, что выдаёт компилятор.

---
Обновил ответ, поправил несколько мелочей.

Comment: Все заработало, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Telsystems: Пожалуйста!

---
Не забудьте, однако, о локали: `ToString` работает в разных локалях по-разному.

Comment: Еще один вопрос. А как сделать, чтобы каждый блок быв на новой строке? 
string.Format("{0}\t{1:d}\n", parts[0], date) - не помогает (

Comment: @Telsystems: Так в коде уже и так на новой строке. Ничего менять не надо. Запустите программу из pastebin, там всё показывает как надо.