# Проверка правильности Image

Tags: c#, wpf

У нас есть Image и TextBlock, через который мы может задавать источник изображения:

```
<Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding ElementName=IconPath, Path=Text}" />
<TextBox x:Name="IconPath"></TextBox>
```

Я могу ввести в TextBox любой текст - путь к файлу, ссылку или просто абракадабру.

Как определить, ведет ли введенный текст к изображению, которое может быть показано в Image? *Другая формулировка вопроса:* Как определить, показывается что-либо в Image или там пусто (например, из-за неверного формата файла)?

Comment: А что вы хотите делать, если в Image пусто? От этого сильно будет зависеть решение

Comment: @АндрейNOP если там пусто, то я хочу просто блокировать условную кнопку "Продолжить"

Comment: Т.е. получение изображения – это часть бизнес-логики приложения?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, если юзер ввел правильный адрес - пускаем дальше, нет - не пускаем.

Comment: В таком случае это должно быть частью vm, заведите в ней свойство для хранения ImageSource, при вводе пути загружайте картинку и если загрузка прошла успешно, включайте команду для продолжения, иначе отключаете ее. Ну и потом желательно загрузку сделать асинхронной и ввести небольшой лаг, чтобы загрузка не происходила при вводе каждого отдельного символа

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вот как раз и интересует, как сделать *при вводе пути загружайте картинку и если загрузка прошла успешно*

Comment: Нет никакого более надежного способа, чем просто загрузить файл по введенному пути и обработать ошибки. Никакие проверки валидности самого пути с помощью регулярок, а также проверки наличия файла `File.Exists` не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ходе подробных тестов выяснилось, что используемая схема привязки неудачна во всех отношениях. Помимо того, что нет легкого способа определить момент завершения загрузки изображения, в случае указания в качестве пути к изображению HTTP URI возникают существенные зависания GUI. Это вызвано тем, что хотя и загрузка BitmapImage по HTTP осуществляется асинхронно, разрешение имени узла все равно осуществляется синхронно. На компьютере, где отключен NetBIOS, скорее всего, это не будет иметь заметного эффекта, однако при включенном NetBIOS любое имя, которое не удалось разрешить в DNS, система будет пытаться разрешить широковещательно и это приведет к заметным зависаниям GUI в ходе ввода пути в TextBox (обновление в данной схеме привязки осуществляется при вводе каждого нового символа).

Вместо этого, я предлагаю создать вспомогательный класс для загрузки изображения в фоновом Task с событием окончания загрузки:

```
public class ImageLoader
{
    Uri _ImageUri;
    BitmapImage _bi;                    

    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get { return _bi; }
    }

    public event EventHandler LoadCompleted;

    void OnLoadCompleted()
    {
        if (LoadCompleted != null) LoadCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
    }        

    public ImageLoader(Uri uri)
    {
        this._ImageUri = uri;           
    }

    void LoadImage()
    {
        BitmapImage bi;
        try
        {
            byte[] data;

            if (_ImageUri.IsFile)
            {
                data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_ImageUri.LocalPath);
            }
            else
            {
                var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                using (client)
                {
                    data = client.DownloadData(_ImageUri);
                }
            }

            var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);

            bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();
            bi.Freeze();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            bi = null;                
        }
        this._bi = bi;            
        OnLoadCompleted();
    }

    public void Run()
    {            
        Task t = new Task(() => LoadImage());
        t.Start();            
    }        
}
```

Привязку TextBox и Image лучше сделать не напрямую, а через вспомогательные свойства:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WpfApplication1" Height="350" Width="620.522" >
    <Grid  >
        <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Path=IconImageSource}" 
               Margin="40,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Image>
        <TextBox x:Name="IconPath" Height="35"
                 Text="{Binding Path=IconPathString, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                 Margin="139,40,40,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=ImageStatusText}"/>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

В код окна добавить логику загрузки изображения и обновления GUI:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }        

        string _IconPathString = "";
        ImageLoader Loader = null;

        public BitmapImage IconImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                if (Loader != null) return Loader.Image;
                else return null;
            }
        }

        string _ImageStatusText="";
        public string ImageStatusText
        {
            get { return _ImageStatusText; }
            set {
                _ImageStatusText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageStatusText");
            }
        }

        public string IconPathString
        {
            get { return _IconPathString; }

            set
            {   
                try
                {
                    if (Loader != null)
                    {
                        Loader.LoadCompleted -= ImageLoadCompleted;
                        Loader = null;
                    }

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        _IconPathString = "";                        
                        OnPropertyChanged("IconImageSource");
                        ImageStatusText = "Введите путь к изображению";                        
                        return;
                    }

                    Uri uri = new Uri(value);
                    Loader = new ImageLoader(uri);
                    Loader.LoadCompleted += ImageLoadCompleted;
                    Loader.Run();
                    _IconPathString = value;
                    ImageStatusText = "Подождите...";   
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    _IconPathString = "";
                    OnPropertyChanged("IconImageSource");
                    ImageStatusText = "Введен неверный путь к изображению";                    
                }
            }
        }

        void ImageLoadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if ((sender as ImageLoader).Image != null)
                {                    
                    ImageStatusText = "Изображение загружено успешно";   
                }
                else
                {                    
                    _IconPathString = "";
                    ImageStatusText = "Введен неверный путь к изображению";   
                }

                OnPropertyChanged("IconImageSource");
                (sender as ImageLoader).LoadCompleted -= ImageLoadCompleted;
            }));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Работает только частично: если вводишь локальный путь. На URL не реагирует никак. А вообще печально, думал что так просто делается универсальное решение).

Comment: @SKProCH Обновил ответ. Естественно, HTTP URI BitmapImage загружает асинхронно, поэтому с ним все сложнее

Comment: Решение работает, только иногда когда вводишь правильный URL после неправильного падает с ошибкой тут: **(ImagePreview.Source as BitmapSource).DownloadFailed -= MainWindow_DownloadFailed;** Ошибка: **System.InvalidOperationException: "Для изменения указанного значения типа "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode" его свойство IsFrozen должно иметь значение "false"."**

Comment: @SKProCH У меня такой ошибки не было. Однако, я нашел в используемом способе привязки другие недостатки. Я предлагаю сделать все вообще по другому.

Answer (score 0):

Данную проблему можна решить путем проверки строки, кратко говоря **проверить на валидность путь**.

Это сделать можно с помощью регулярного выражения, например: взять распарсить строку, и просмотреть или в ней находится .jpp|png|svg, если есть, проходим первый этап, дальше попытаться обратиться к картинке, если никаких проблем при этом не возникло, все хорошо.

Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/328051/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) парсинга строки, а [вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.2.php) работа со строками, ну и [регулярные выражения](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.4.php).

Comment: Это ясно, я тоже думал над таким решением, но думал, что есть какое-либо более специализированное решение

Comment: @SKProCH в вашем случае это самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: Это плохое решение, если даже путь валиден, не факт что он существует и не факт что он доступен и не факт что там лежит файл в корректном формате. @SKProCH

Comment: @Aqua, поясните, пожалуйста, свое заявление

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну почему так не подойдёт? В регулярке проверять формат. А после если путь валидный сделать проверку на File.Exist и все. Чем такой вариант плох? Или обернуть все в try{}catch и ловить исключение если путь не валидный. ИМХО

Comment: Полностью согласен с @Aqua!

Comment: @АндрейNOP прочитайте внимательно решение.

Comment: @Aqua, если даже файл существует, не факт что он будет существовать через мгновение, когда вы соберётесь его загрузить, также в качестве пути может выступать ссылка на ресурс в сети

Comment: @Dmitry, приведите, пожалуйста, код, в вашем ответе решения пока нет, только общие фразы. В какой момент эти проверки надо делать и как задействовать их в привязке?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, что значит файл не будет доступен, при чтение файла мы будем использовать конструкцию `using`  и если что-то пойдет не так, поток закроется. Про ресурс из сети тут речь вообще не идет...

Comment: @Dmitry, а почему не может по ресурс в сети? В вопросе такой вариант упоминается и вообще не обязательно при этом иметь ".jpg" на конце

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я бы с радостью это сделал, но я навел автора данного вопроса, на возможный вариант решения его проблемы, к сожалению приводить примеры, сейчас нет времени.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, если вы знаете решение лучше, прошу его описать. А по поводу ресурса из сети, нужно другое решение, более пластичное. Здесь я с вами соглашусь.

Comment: Пока не совсем понятно что требуется автору, задал уточняющий вопрос

Comment: Для проверки расширения файла регулярные выражения не нужны, можно использовать стандартный метод System.IO.Path.GetExtension

Answer (score -1):

Вот готовый вариант который можно использовать. Лично моё мнение, достаточно нормальной проверки строки на валидность, а после на наличие элемента по данному пути.

Составил регулярное выражение

***(если что не так, прошу великих гуру отписаться в комментарий)***,

подходит только для полного пути, *т.е. `D:\\MyFiles\Pictures\pict211.png`*.

Делаем проверку строки, соответствует ли она паттерну, и на наличие файла по заданному пути методом `Exist` из статического класса `File`

Вот примерный код:

```
if (new Regex(@"[A-Z]:\\\\(\w+\\)+\w+((.png)|(.jpeg))").IsMatch(IconPath.Text)
      && File.Exists(IconPath.Text))
{
    //делаем то что нам нужно.
}
```

А вообще, вам бы проверки на наличие, было бы достаточно. Ведь если мы в качестве аргумента передадим *абракадабру*, то метод просто вернет `false`.

### Удачи в изучении C#

**Aqua**

---

### P.S.

Не сильно напрягался с расширением файла, если нужны другие форматы делайте вот так:

```
[A-Z]:\\\\(\w+\\)+\w+((.png)|(.jpeg)|(.format№3)|(.format№4)|...)
```

*где вместо `format№n` пишем нужное нам расширение.*

Comment: Прошу того кто ставит минус, объяснить неправильность моего подхода, в комментарии.

Comment: То же самое: для проверки расширения файла регулярные выражения не нужны. Можно использовать стандартный метод System.IO.Path.GetExtension

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight согласитесь, что вообще можно не проверять путь на валидность. Можно просто проверку на существования файла по пути. Если путь не валидный, результат будет false.

Comment: Работающий вариант, но если будет ссылка?